# Slow connection with raspberry when "/" is on external hard drive

Tags: boot, usb, ssh, hard-drive

So far i've tried `minibian`, `arch (alarmpi)` and `arkOS` and, when I'm lucky I get to connect by ssh. Whenever I'm able to do so ssh manages to freeze randomly.

I've changed de `/boot/cmdline.txt` at `/dev/mmcblk0p1` so that I boot from hdd and the `/etc/fstab` to point to automount and check the "`/`" partition.

I've seen arrownd the internet how peope use their USB hard drives without problem so maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The external hard drive needs more power than it's supplied with and therefore doesn't perform as expected . a powered  USB hub solves this. There is a malfunction due to the lack of power during boot

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading the root of your boot drive over a USB 2.0 connection it is going to be slow. Try caching to a ram drive.

Comment: Seems like it's my USB HDD fault. People get this working just by changing the `/` partition on theyr `cmdline.txt` and it works fine. I'll try another HDD and close the question if it's this infact.